# How do I change used browser to "Open Org" service for my authorized org in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce

I'm using VSCode and latest salesforce cli (v2), I've authorized my org and everything is working good.

When I click on the icon in the pic (part of Salesforce CLI Integration extension)

[image]

it runs my system default browser (firefox) with my org.

I just want to use chrome for this operation, but I'd like not to switch to chrome as system default browser.

How can I set the browser to use for this operation?

There's nothing useful in Salesforce CLI Integration extension settings.
I even tried to install Live Server extension to set the browser to use there, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you make yourself a shortcut or small script in the project's folder or something like that with `sf org open --browser=chrome`? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_org_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_org_open_unified

Comment: Yeah I know I can run that corresponding command on terminal, but would be nicer to make it happen by clicking that icon